# Error C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, directx-12

I'm trying to make a dynamic array in C++ using DirectX 12. I found a good one on here made some miner changes because it was created for DirectX 11.

I get this error when I run it.

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
>
> Error C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Here is the code it is saying has the issue.

```
    Vector(int a)
{
  size = a;
  obj = new T[size];
  for(int i = 0 ; i<size; i++)
  {
    obj[i] = NULL;
  }
}
```

Here is the full header.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Vector
{
private:
    int size,capacity;
    T *obj;
public:
    Vector()
    {
        size = capacity = 0;
        obj = NULL;
    }
    ~Vector()
    {
        delete [] obj;
    }
    Vector(int a)
    {
        size = a;
        obj = new T[size];
        for(int i = 0 ; i<size; i++)
        {
            obj[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    int size_of_list();
    bool empty();
    void reserve(int);
    T& operator[](int);
    T at(int);
    T front();
    T back();
    void push_back(T element);
    void pop_back();
    void insert(int,T);
    void erase(int);
};
```

The .cpp file is available on request.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: What is type T? You are attempting to assign NULL to it, but that's only going to be valid if T is a pointer, which you have not specified.

Comment: You should read a good C++ book before proceeding.

Comment: T would be the Type, so in this case an int

Comment: There's nothing in the shown code that indicates that `T` is an int. If it were an `int`, then, yes, it will not work, since the shown code attempts to assign a `NULL` to an `int` which, of course, will not work.

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. If you need a vector, why don't you just use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

You're writing java or C#, not c++ there. C++ has value semantics. Objects generally can't be set to NULL (which is just a macro for the value zero). Nor is there any need, generally, as you have a proper value: `T{}`, the default constructed object

Comment: Thank you, Im not very knowledgeable of C++ and this is linked with a uni project, I had tried it with setting it to equal 0 but that give the same error. so if im right your saying i dont need this anyway?

Comment: @jshone94: 0 or `NULL` are pretty much the same. Exactly what does it mean to have a `Vector<ChessBoardPosition>` with `ChessBoardPosition` set to `0`? Does that even make sense? No - you're assuming that any type `T` can be assigned the value `0`, and that's just not true.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you are assuming that obj[i] is a pointer to a type T, but it actually is an object of type T. obj is a pointer to the first allocated T object, obj[i] it the T object at address obj + i*sizeof(T)